# Waiting on transform from /base_footprint to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error:

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, p3at, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to auto navigate my P3AT.

Using ROS-Fuertr (on PC1: UBUNTU 12.04 LTS) & USARSim (on PC2: windows7 ).

I have my launch file move_base.launch,

```
<launch>

  <master auto="start"/>
  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/map/map.pgm 0.05"/>

  <!--- You can see original move_base.launch -->
  <!--- Run AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find usarsim_inf)/launch/usarsim.launch"/>
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_omni.launch" />
  
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/launch/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
    </node>
  
</launch>
```

but when i try,

```
$ roslaunch my_robot_name_2dnav move_base.launch
```

i am getting an warning message,

```
[ WARN] [1413488778.937642524]: Waiting on transform from /base_footprint to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error:
```

[see here the full terminal output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgpkuoh65m3mepg/automated-issue.docx?dl=0)

please help to improve this scenario.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195175/waiting-on-transform-from-/base_footprint-to-/map-to-become-available-before-running-costmap,-tf-error:/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

amcl was not getting the laser data from the /scan topic, i fix it and solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) with karma: 351 on 2014-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-24**:
how do you solved it?

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2015-05-02**:
hi @pexison, my simulator was publishing laser scan on `lms200` topic instead of `/scan` , i remapped the the publishing from `lms200` to `/scan` and that worked form me...
if your laser data is being published on `/scan` topic then you might look on  time on both the PCs, the should be synchronize

**Comment by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on 2017-05-15**:
Hi @Aarif, Please tell how did you change the topic from lms200 to /scan?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check a couple of things:

1. Is the time on both the PCs synchronised? It's possible that the time is different across both your machines. In which case, you can set up an NTP server on one of them to synchronise time.
2. Use the following commands to debug

> rosrun tf view_frames

> rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_footprint

(and show us the output of that if you aren't able to figure it out)

Also, there should be a few other related questions on this website since this is a common error and the tf tutorials has help on common pitfalls.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2